# Sliding menus all coming out at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu

I have a nav bar, what I need is that when you click on an link its corresponding DIV should slide down/up.

My problems are that all the DIVs are sliding down and when clicking on the same link all DIVs AND the nva items slide up.

How can I make this work right?

**My HTML:**

```
<div id="megamenus" class="click-menu">
  <h6><span>Products &amp; Services</span></h6>
  <h6><span>Support &amp; Training</span></h6>
  <h6><span>Communities</span></h6>
  <h6 class="new-window"><span>Store</span></h6>

  <div class="menu-container">aaaa</div>    
  <div class="menu-container" id="training-n-support">bbbb</div>
  <div class="menu-container">cccc</div>
</div>
```

**My jQuery:**

```
$('.click-menu div.menu-container').hide();
$('.click-menu h6 span').click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
    $(this).removeClass('selected');
    $(this).parent().siblings().stop(true, true).slideUp('slow', function() {
        $('h4').css('z-index', '1');
    });

 } else {
    $('.click-menu h6 span').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $('.click-menu div.menu-container').slideUp('slow');
    $(this).parent().siblings().stop(true, true).slideDown('');
    $('h4').css('z-index', '0');
 }
});
```

Here's the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/BGBaH/).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are telling all `siblings` of the parent to slide, not qualifying it further like this `.siblings('selector-for-intended-element')`

See JsFiddle for my recommendation : http://jsfiddle.net/BGBaH/1/

I recommend you put the divs directly after the menu items, and just use `.next()`

**UPDTE**

If you don't want to do that, here is a jsfiddle that more closely resembles what you originally asked for I believe

http://jsfiddle.net/BGBaH/2/

I just added id's to your span menu items, and added matching classes to the corresponding divs.  Then I qualified the `.siblings()` function with the proper class selector.

Comment: jondavidjohn, thanks for your reply. Your first demo has a similar issue to mine, if you click the nav element, all other nav elements hide. However, your second demo worked great, I will use that one. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: The reason I accepted your solution if because the HTML structure is exactly the same as I needed it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**

> - **DEMO:** http://jsbin.com/owete4/3

```
.menu-container { display:none }
```

---

```
$(function() {
    $('#megamenus h6').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
          $('#megamenus div').slideUp(500);
          $(this).next('div:not(:visible)').slideDown(500);
    });
});
```

---

```
    <div id="megamenus" class="click-menu">
        <h6><span>Products &amp; Services</span></h6>
        <div class="menu-container">dddd</div>
        <h6><span>Store</span></h6>
        <div class="menu-container">aaaa</div>
        <h6><span>Support &amp; Training</span></h6>
        <div class="menu-container">bbbb</div>
        <h6><span>Communities</span></h6>
        <div class="menu-container">cccc</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: aSeptik, thanks for your reply. However, although I could technically change my HTML structure to fit your example, I can't now because there are many other things styled using the shown structure.

Comment: aSeptik, the sliding menus don't slide back up when clicking on its corresponding link. I need to maintain the same HTML structure I mentioned above ^_^. I liked the other solution you linked to before, do you still have that link? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Awesome! I'll keep this one as an alternate solution. Gave you a vote. Thanks!

Comment: do you have tried the last update? http://jsbin.com/owete4/3 it work as expected...! with less code. ;)

Comment: Yeah, I saw your update, I forgot to mention it in my last comment :p. Thanks again.